# xHCI causes "USB device not recognized" until reboot

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

When I enable xHCI in my BIOS, I get three times faster speed (90 MB/s file copying in Windows Explorer) with my external hard drive, but paradoxically I get the message "USB device can perform faster". Most problematically, I get "USB device not recognized" on one of my two USB 3.0 ports until I reboot with the hard drive being plugged in.

When I disable xHCI, these problems disappear, but I get three times slower speed (even though the [purpose of xHCI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Host_Controller_Interface#Architectural_goals) doesn't seem to be about transfer speed).

Are there any settings that might fix all these problems rather than just a subset of problems?

Comment: Are you using the latest driver for your xHCI controller?

Comment: @Nassbirne My manufacturer doesn't offer xHCI controller drivers in their list of drivers. Could they be part of some other drivers, for example chipset drivers? Otherwise how do I find out what kind of xHCI controller I have / which drivers I need? I use new drivers that are offered.

Comment: What hardware do you have?

Comment: I'd try the following driver: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/22824/Intel-USB-3-0-eXtensible-Host-Controller-Driver-for-Intel-8-9-100-Series-and-Intel-C220-C610-Chipset-Family